# Grunt task that restarts my app via command line

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, gruntjs, sails.js

I'm looking for a Grunt task that would restart my [Sails](http://sailsjs.org/) app. Currently, the only way I know how to restart a Sails app is going to the terminal where the app is running and enter 'Ctrl + C'. Then 'Sails lift' to start it up again. Is there a way that Grunt can run these two commands for me?

I got close using this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell, but couldn't quite take it home. Any advice?

**EDIT**:
The following successfully kill the Sails app via the command line, but the Grunt task (below) still causes an error when I try to start the Sails app:
`pkill -2 node /usr/local/bin/sails` and `pkill -SIGINT node /usr/local/bin/sails`

The code in my Grunt task is:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('shell', {
        multiple: {
            command: [
                'pkill -SIGINT node /usr/local/bin/sails',
                'sails lift'
            ].join('&&')
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
};
```

(I'm using this Grunt task: https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell)

And when I try to start the app ("Sails lift") I get a "Command failed" error. I think it has to do with the fact that I'm trying to kill the app with the app itself. Or something.

Answer (score 2):

pkill can be used to kill a process based on its name instead of PID

```
pkill -SIGINT {name of process} && Sails lift
```

This should do what you need. You can find the name of the process pretty easily by doing a top or a ps aux | grep "sail"

Im sure the process is just sails, so it would likely be:

```
pkill -SIGINT sails && Sails lift
```

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + C sends SIGINT (see signal(7)), so if you can use shell commands, use the kill command like this:

```
kill -SIGINT {pid-of-your-Sails-app} && Sails lift
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I actually tried this before, but the pid changes each time you restart the app. Is there a way to make the pid field dynamic within the grunt task?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using nodemon for this task and it works great:

https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, since if the link changes the info is lost,.  You should post the relevant details that answes this question, at the very least.